# Searching pattern in awk from variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have data input data:

```
AAA
AAA
AA
BBB
BB
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

search_pattern=AA

awk '-v search='$search_pattern' /search/ {count ++}END {print count, "/", NR} ' input
```

Desire output is:

```
1 / 5
```

1. Problem is: when I use variable `$search_pattern` - awk show output only: `/ 5`
2. How to "tell" awk to search only AA (not AAA) = force PATTERN to match only whole words

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:

Would be possible to add condition, if does not match any string, print `0 / 5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search will take other strings too which will have this string in them, so try following.

```
var="AA"    
awk -v VAR="$var" '$0 == VAR{count++;} END{print count " / " NR}'  Input_file
```

Or with your shown variable names etc.

```
search_pattern=AA
awk -v search="$search_pattern" '$0 == search {count++}END {print count, "/", NR}' Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** OP added additional requirement of adding 0 to output if no matches found for string into Input_file, following may help in same.

```
awk -v search="$search_pattern" '$0 == search {count++}END {print count?count:0, "/", NR}'  Input_file
```

Comment: hi, thank you for a response. But still show me empty first place like  / 5, any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please make sure that variable is set with value? I mean shell variable? Let me know on same then as I am getting correct output only.

Comment: I see in your first example you have variable var in double quotes. Is this necessary?

Comment: With " or without it should work, that is only to save it from those characters which may have special meaning if there any in variable value. I tested in both and it did work, kindly show me how you are running it?

Comment: My code is: #!/bin/bash

search_pattern="31116441"


awk -v search="$search_pattern" '$0 == search {count ++}END {print count,"/",NR}' input

Comment: I edited Input_file provided by you and set the variable again then It is working fine for me, so can you please make sure this is present intp your Input_file also? As I can't see it your shown Input_file. Let me know on same. EDIT_comment: I added condition for showing 0 also into EDIT section in answer, please have a look to it too now.

Comment: yes it is input_file. It was typo. But still does not work. If I change only #!/bin/bash

awk '$0 == 31116441 {count ++}END {print count,"/",NR}' testing_database it is does not work either.

Comment: This one works : awk -v search= '/31116441/ {count ++}END {print count,"/",NR}' testing_database (testing_database = input_file)

Comment: I have strong feeling that you may have carriage characters in your Input_file, so could you please check following things now, I- Can you check if there are control M chars into your Input_file by doing "cat -v Input_file". II- If yes then try do remove them from "tr -d < Input_file > temp_Input_file && mv temp_Input_file Input_file". Let me know how it goes then.

Comment: I already checked and no control M char. MY $SHELL is ZSH. Could be a problem there?

Comment: It could be a problem, I don't have ZSH with me, sorry can't test it. Will try online terminals and try to test it, if I find any.

Comment: Anyway very thank you for your time and good solution. I will wait a little bit and then accept. Still, have no idea where the hell is a problem.

Comment: I think your problem is that the search pattern is not getting passed in correctly.  Try adding search to the print line, e.g. print search, count , "/", NR.  It's likely going to show "$search_pattern".

Comment: Good idea - yes this is print my search pattern - $search_pattenr

Comment: Never worked on zsh but how about escaping " to \" in -v part once, give it a try and let us know then.

Comment: Still empty output. I notice, that in my ZSH $0 == search does not work, but $0 ~ search works. But right now it does not match the whole word.

Comment: awk version is GNU Awk 4.0.1

Comment: The problem was in my data. I am using @RavinderSingh13 solution and part of solution. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Ravinder's solution is correct.  Just adding this as another way using pattern matching.

```
search_pattern=^AA$
awk -v search="$search_pattern" 'BEGIN{count=0} $0 ~ search {count++} END{print count, "/", NR}' input
```

^ = beginning of the line.

$ = end of the line.

So, AAA would not be counted.

Comment: Yes this is works. But It counting AA and AAA - so I have 3/5 instead 1/5. So I need to match only whole words.. Any idea?

Comment: With this pattern, AAA should not be counted.

Comment: Thank you. I am testing on differetn search pattern, but - grep -c ^31116441$ input = 0 and grep -c 31116441 input = 26. Again ZSH "problem"?

Comment: I doubt ZSH would be the issue.  What do you see from this:  grep 31116441 input | awk '{ printf("[%s]", $0) }'

Comment: that works - It changes my columns to lines in Square bracket like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149506/discussion-between-flu-and-geroge).